# Linux distribution vulnerable to buffer overflow

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow

i need to demonstrate Buffer overflow in class.Could anyone suggest me distribution and the place where i can download it from.

i tried DVL,but it doesnt provide the desired output.

Comment: You could try metasploitable...

Comment: Slackware 7 (an example) is well know to have several bugs. Install a kernel 2.0 or 2.2 and you will find a **lot** of buffer overflow exploits

Comment: does this mean if i download slackware 7...i will have to recompile the kernel with 2.2 or would it already be 2.2....the reason i am asking this is bcos i have tried a few old distribution but all seems to have kernel 2.6..

Comment: You can write your own *faulty* daemon and run it on any distribution you like to demonstrate that, to show how important it is that all components of the system get exhaustively tested before shipping it as a product. But I don't think you are looking for this option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a *really old* version from a few years back.

Comment: I like Debian and there should be some.  Older Ubuntus should work too.